# How to extract the URL of a crypto art as it appears within the NFT? and technical details like ERC-token type?

Tags: erc-721, nft, erc-1155

The following piece of crypto art has a title, description, and additional details regarding file and image size, provided by the NFT platform (Makersplace) where the artist (Lumi) minted the NFT for the image.

- https://makersplace.com/lumi/trajectory-3-of-10-48596/

How can I view the URL link to the associated image file as it appears within the metadata/code of the NFT itself? and get technical details such as whether the NFT is an ERC-721 or ERC-1155 token?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find that particular piece in their contracts, but the below applies to the 2 of 10 edition.

> How can I view the URL link to the associated image file as it appears within the metadata/code of the NFT itself?

The 2 of 10 edition is [here](https://makersplace.com/authenticity/0x2a46f2ffd99e19a89476e2f62270e0a35bbf0756/42497/).

From that we see their contract - MakersTokenV2 - is at [0x2a46f2ffd99e19a89476e2f62270e0a35bbf0756](https://etherscan.io/address/0x2a46f2ffd99e19a89476e2f62270e0a35bbf0756).

You can use Etherscan to read data from the contract [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x2a46f2ffd99e19a89476e2f62270e0a35bbf0756#readContract).

The token ID is 42497, which we can use with the `tokenURI()` method from that Etherscan page, to get the following as the location of the artwork's metadata (not the artwork itself):

ipfs://ipfs/QmdNvqCbd7qYvtyFJdd3zoJC84cvyCiSxYDfsiYYQZVCec

Which is an IPFS path. To view it through a browser requires you to use a gateway:

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmdNvqCbd7qYvtyFJdd3zoJC84cvyCiSxYDfsiYYQZVCec

From there we can see the image's metadata, which includes the actual location of the art:

```
{
  title: 'Trajectory',
  name: 'Trajectory',
  type: 'object',
  imageUrl:
    'https://ipfsgateway.makersplace.com/ipfs/QmNopeEan1r728EGpAYZw8fFvCXfuXtnadC3JCeY5mo9LB',
  description: 'Created by artist ThinkLumi',
  attributes: [
    {
      trait_type: 'Creator',
      value: 'Think Lumi',
    },
  ],
  properties: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      description: 'Trajectory',
    },
    description: {
      type: 'string',
      description: 'Created by artist ThinkLumi',
    },
    preview_media_file: {
      type: 'string',
      description:
        'https://ipfsgateway.makersplace.com/ipfs/QmNopeEan1r728EGpAYZw8fFvCXfuXtnadC3JCeY5mo9LB',
    },
    preview_media_file_type: {
      type: 'string',
      description: 'jpg',
    },
    created_at: {
      type: 'datetime',
      description: '2020-05-06T18:24:35.578285+00:00',
    },
    total_supply: {
      type: 'int',
      description: 10,
    },
    digital_media_signature_type: {
      type: 'string',
      description: 'SHA-256',
    },
    digital_media_signature: {
      type: 'string',
      description:
        '72fd9dc05cc5b630c28d749eb56dc4f99173e6769556f7ac10c8204dd1de8721',
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: does any of the metadata indicate the NFT being an ERC-721 or ERC-1155?

Comment: It doesn't, but their FAQ says that everything is ERC-721 -> https://makersplace.com/faq/. See the "Non-fungible tokens" section.

Comment: based on the field `imageUrl`, if `https://ipfsgateway.makersplace.com/ipfs/` is taken down, being merely a web gateway to the actual IPFS location of the art, then the link to the crypto art will cease to exist, even though it's still up on IPFS?

Comment: That appears to be their own IPFS gateway, meaning they must be running their own IPFS node. If that gets taken down then the art will still exist in IPFS, like you say. But that particular link won't correctly resolve. The IPFS hash part of the link could still be used as an identifier though (`QmNopeEan1r728EGpAYZw8fFvCXfuXtnadC3JCeY5mo9LB`)

Comment: (And any service displaying the art could scrape that identifier from the metadata and run it through a different gateway.)

Comment: where is the `tokenURI()` method from a contract's Etherscan page? i can't see it anywhere on the page

Comment: The page I linked to (under the Contract tab, then Read Contract), and it's method #23. https://etherscan.io/address/0x2a46f2ffd99e19a89476e2f62270e0a35bbf0756#readContract

Comment: pressing the Query button there gives "Error: Invalid number of parameters for "tokenURI". Got 0 expected 1!" It works when I enter 42497

Comment: The method must be passed a parameter - you are asking the contract for the URI associated with a particular token, so you have to pass it a token ID else it will complain in the way that you found :-)